# Add class to reusable pane

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-panels

Seems like this should be easy but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a static class to all instances of a reusable content pane. The default classes are nonspecific (pane-1, pane-2, etc) but it would seem to be helpful to have a class that's unique to the pane so when it is reused on other pages the css will automatically apply. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick. Allows you to add all sorts of classes to all sorts of things. Nice module: https://drupal.org/project/clean_markup.